# How to resolve Unparseable date Exception in Java 8 with Date format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a text file from which I am reading and setting transaction POJO class data, to get the difference between start and end time I need to parse the time information in date object.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
System.out.println("Date format in play:"+dateFormat);
Transaction transaction = storageRepositroy.getTransaction(key);
Date start = format.parse(transaction.getStartDate() + " " + transaction.getStartTime());//line no. 29
Date end = format.parse(transaction.getEndDate() + " " + transaction.getEndTime());
```

I am getting exception while running this code

Exception is

```
Date format in play:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020–03–01 03:15 PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at dc.tech.transaction.util.TimeUtil.calculateAverageTime(TimeUtil.java:29)
```

yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a is the date format which I am passing to SimleDateFormat constructor. I am unable to understand and debug why I am getting this error.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: you have hyphen character issue in your file, if you manually type the hyphen for test your code works

Comment: both of them are other characters. hyphen should have ascii 45 but your character gives ascii 8211. hyphen in 2020–03–01 . notice here only – and -

Comment: Quick and dirty approach would be to use "yyyy–MM–dd hh:mm a" as dateFormat since your data itself has hyphen as –

Comment: I didn’t downvote (I did the opposite). Your code example is not complete/self-contained, and you may improve your question by [providing one that is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It was good enough that @Ajeetkumar was able to spot what was wrong, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu\u2013MM\u2013dd");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String dateString = "2020–03–01";
    String timeString = "03:15 PM";
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, timeFormatter);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2020-03-01T15:15

With java.time it is straightforward to combine date and time after parsing, so I prefer to parse them individually.

### What went wrong in your code?

Credits go to Ajeetkumar for noticing and reporting in comments: The hyphen in your date string is not a usual minus sign or hyphen with character value 2D hexadecimal (45 decimal), but a *en dash* with character value 2013 hexadecimal (8211 decimal). So when you specify a usual hyphen in your format pattern string, they don’t match, and parsing fails. Instead I am using a Unicode escape for putting the en dash into the format pattern string. Simply pasting it in there would have worked too (provided that you save your .java file with a character encoding that supports it), but I wanted to make the reader aware that something special was going on here, so I preferred the Unicode escape with `\u`.

There is another problem with your code: You are not providing any locale for your formatter. So it uses the default locale of your JVM. As long as that locale expects `PM`, parsing will work. If one day you change your locale setting or run your code on a computer or JVM with a different default locale, parsing will suddenly fail, at you may have a hard time figuring out why. I have specified English locale for parsing the time. Some would prefer doing it for the date too even though technically it isn’t necessary.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) on FileFormat.info.

Answer (score 2):

**I always stick to this mantra:** use exactly the same format as your date-time string.

In the solutions given below, I have copied your date-time string into the pattern that I've specified for `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter` and replaced the numbers with the corresponding letters e.g. `2020` with `yyyy` while keeping the rest of things (symbols, space etc.) intact.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy–MM–dd hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);// Make sure to use Locale
        String dateTimeString = "2020–03–01 03:15 PM";// The string copied from the exception you have got
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020–03–01 03:15 PM
```

**Note:** The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy–MM–dd hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);// Make sure to use Locale
        String dateTimeString = "2020–03–01 03:15 PM";// The string copied from the exception you have got
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-03-01T15:15
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).